# How to create a nested db transaction in Laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel

```
DB::beginTransaction();

// ... some SQL queries here ...

$requestApi = RequestApi::send($data);

if(!$requestApi->status) {
    return response()->json(['error' => 'Error message'], 500);
}

DB::commit();
```

This is a simple example of my query, in the `RequestApi` class there is a create database log query in each API request. How to implement nested database transactions in laravel, I want when the API response status is false it will only save log data.

Comment: So why don't you take `$requestApi = RequestApi::send($data);` out of the transac ?

Comment: @ml59 I thought like that, but it would be problematic, RequestApi doesn't always produce a true response. If I move it outside the transaction and the response is false, the previous SQL query will still run.

Comment: why not send the api request, check the response and only if success run your query?